# SonarQube 5.3 Attemps Starting then Stops

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I've looked at SonarQube for quite a while and is now in a position where I would need it where I currently work. To begin with though, I try to install it locally and have it analyze one of our projects before committing it to a server environment. But installing SonarQube has proven to be more troublesome than first assumed.

I went to the SonarQube website to check out the documentation on how to set it up. My current setup is:

- Windows 7 64-Bit
- JDK 7 Update 79
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012

So I went into the SonarQube properties to start setting it  up. I got the following settings:

- sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://obscured;databaseName=sonar;integratedSecurity=true
- sonar.jdbc.maxActive=60
- sonar.jdbc.maxIdle=5
- sonar.jdbc.minIdle=2
- sonar.jdbc.maxWait=5000
- sonar.jdbc.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=600000
- sonar.jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=30000
- sonar.web.host=192.0.0.1
- sonar.web.context=/sonar
- sonar.web.port=9000

When I try to run StartSonar.bat (as Admin) it gives me this in the sonar.log file:

```
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2016.04.13 10:32:08 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true # -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 # -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\smf\Documents\sonarqube-5.3\temp -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer C:\Users\smf\AppData\Local\Temp\sq-process4147018529192614354properties
Error: Could not find or load main class #
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I am not sure why it can't find the main class. I have not done anything to alter the file structure. It has simply been extracted in Documents as it's own folder (C:\Users\smf\Documents\sonarqube-5.3).

On a side-note, I have been unable to use the Windows Service option. I can install the service, but whenever I try and start it, I'm told that the service launched but failed to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about the `#`:

> Could not find or load main class **#**

That's because there is a `#` that doesn't belong there when the Java process is being launched:

```
-Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true # -XX:+UseParNewGC
```

And my bet is that this `#` comes from the following in your `sonar.properties` file:

```
sonar.search.javaOpts=-Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
#  -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 \
#  -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

i.e. you would have only uncommented the first line, but the trailing `\` at the end of that line means that the next lines are not treated as  comment but are passed as JVM options, `#` included.

Two solutions:

- remove the trailing `\` on the first line
- preferred solution: uncomment the two remaining lines